# org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException getting errow in android 4

Tags: android, apache-poi

I have got error in android version 4

```
 E/ExcelSheet: null
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:62)
  at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:456)
  at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:162)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:271)
  at com.example.vinove.excelsheetapp.Poi.ExcelSheet.readExcelSheet(ExcelSheet.java:63)
  at com.example.vinove.excelsheetapp.Activities.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:137)
  at com.example.vinove.excelsheetapp.Activities.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:107)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
  at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:456) 
  at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:162) 
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:271) 
  at com.example.vinove.excelsheetapp.Poi.ExcelSheet.readExcelSheet(ExcelSheet.java:63) 
  at com.example.vinove.excelsheetapp.Activities.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:137) 
  at com.example.vinove.excelsheetapp.Activities.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:107) 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.ThemeDocument$Factory
  at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:46)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: i have got error in android version 4.something

Comment: That's only half the stack trace, and missing the reason for the error - what does the "caused by" bit of the stacktrace say?

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI will not work out of the box on Android, there are various problems that you will run into.

There are some projects that make it possible to use parts of Apache POI on Android:

1. https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx (for Android 5) and https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX (for Android 4) which is based on Apache POI 3.12
2. https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ (for Android 5, maintained by me), which can be used with any version of POI, e.g. 3.15 currently